# What's up with this cat?

Tags: uzaki-chan-wa-asobitai

In Uzaki-chan wa Asobitai! (Uzaki-chan Wants to Hang Out!), there's this cat that's often shown in random moments in the anime. I've finished the anime and I still don't understand the significance or the need for this cat to be focused upon on certain scenes. It didn't interact with the characters nor affected them. Is there some reason why this cat is being shown in the anime?
[image]